# Java. Как заменить блок if-else на полиморфизм?

Tags: java, ооп, if, полиморфизм

У меня вот такой код мне дали задание разбить метод на классы так что-бы использовался полиморфизм. Помогите хорошей идеей что тут можно сделать?

```
private void start() {
        System.out.println("Помощь: \"h\"");
        ArrayList<String> target = null;
        String command;
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            command = scanner.nextLine();
            while (!"q".equals(command)) {
                if ("-f".equals(command)) {
                    // можно сделать
                    System.out.println("Введите полное имя директории для поиска в формате \"absolute path.../dir\":");
                    Dir dir = new Dir(scanner.nextLine());
                    System.out.println("Введите имя файла для поиска:");
                    target = dir.searchByName(scanner.nextLine());
                    target.forEach(System.out::println);
                } else if ("-r".equals(command)) {
                    System.out.println("Введите полное имя директории для поиска в формате \"absolute path.../dir\":");
                    Dir dir = new Dir(scanner.nextLine());
                    System.out.println("Введите часть имени файла для поиска:");
                    target = dir.searchRegExp(scanner.nextLine());
                    System.out.println("Найдено:");
                    target.forEach(System.out::println);
                } else if ("-o".equals(command)) {
                    if (target != null) {
                        System.out.println("Введите полное имя директории куда сохранить файл в формате \"absolute path.../dir/\":");
                        String path = scanner.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Введите имя файла в формате \"file.extension\":");
                        String name = scanner.nextLine();
                        // получаем каталог куда сохранять
                        if (this.exist(path, name)) {
                            this.write(target, path + name);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Действие не возможно.");
                        }
                    }
                } else if ("h".equals(command)) {
                    printManual();
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Неизвестная команда.");
                    printManual();
                }
                command = scanner.nextLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: А может быть проще посмотреть паттерн проектирования `Команда`  и сделать по нему?

Comment: Вы уверены, что это нужно заменять полиморфизмом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно объявить несколько классов и один интерфейс. Далее, в цикле `while` пробегаться по коллекции объектов реализующих данный класс, сравнивать названия и при совпадении вызывать метод `invoke`

```
public interface Command{
    String getName();
    void invoke(Scanner scanner);
}

public class FirstCommand implements Command {
    public String getName(){
       return "-f";
    }
    public void invoke(Scanner scanner){
      // можно сделать
      System.out.println("Введите полное имя директории для поиска в формате \"absolute path.../dir\":");
      Dir dir = new Dir(scanner.nextLine());
      System.out.println("Введите имя файла для поиска:");
      ArrayList<String> target = dir.searchByName(scanner.nextLine());
      target.forEach(System.out::println);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Интересно... А как цикл while будет выглядеть? Как мне связать instanceof с стринговым флагом. Флаг то мне придет из консоли вот на пример "-f" как в примере, а дальше все равно получится if("-f".equals( и пошло поехало... Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: создаете перед циклом while Collection<Command>  commands, и по ней бегаете при получении  новой команды, дергая метод getName, если есть совпадение, то вызываете следом invoke иначе переходите к следующему элементу

Comment: Понял спасибо!  Это то что надо!